# Issues with writing to a txt file after transmitting a small textfile using a C# TcpClient

Tags: c#, android, stream, tcpclient

I use below code to transfer a small text file (15kB) between a client and a server and store the file as a textfile on the serverside. The client is sending the file line-by-line and all is received by the server. (This has been confirmed by displaying the last data send by the client and the last data received by the server).

The client is an Android app running on a Smartphone, the server is on my PC.
As said, all data is transferred correctly and completly, but for some reason the server doesn't write all the data to the .txt file. It looks like that when it reached the "break" it also stops writing.

I have tried several options:

1. reading the .txt file line-by-line, adding the received line to a List array and after all has received write to the file
2. sending and receiving from the client character-by character
3. reading the .txt file line-by-line and writing each line to the .txt file (current code)

With each option the written file stops at the same point. What am I missing here?

The code so far

Client (Android application)

```
    public static class Globals
    {
        public static String FileCaracters = "HOME_Characters.txt";
        public static String Datafiles= @"sdcard/Android/data";
    }


        protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CameraLayout);
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            Button sendButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
    sendButton.Click +=(sender, e) => {
                    try
                    {
                        string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Globals.Datafiles, Globals.FileCaracters);
                        System.IO.FileInfo fL = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(Globals.Datafiles, Globals.FileCaracters));
                        TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
                        tcpclnt.Connect("192.168.1.68", 2002);
                        Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
                        {
                            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                            {
                                ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                                byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(sr.ReadLine());
                                stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
                            }
                        }                
                        tcpclnt.Close();
                    }

                    catch (System.Exception f)
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "Error..... " + f, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }

                };
}
```

Server side (Windows.Forms application)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Socket s;
    TcpListener myList
    public StreamWriter SR = new StreamWriter("test.txt");
    try
    {
        IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.68");
        myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 2002);

        myList.Start();

        textBox2.Text = "The server is running at port 2002...";textBox2.Refresh();
        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + "The local End point is  :" +
                          myList.LocalEndpoint; textBox2.Refresh();
        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Waiting for a connection....."; textBox2.Refresh();

        s = myList.AcceptSocket();

        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint; textBox2.Refresh();

        while (true)
        {
            str = "";
            byte[] b = new byte[1000];
            int k = s.Receive(b);
            if (k == 0)
            {
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + "\nSent Acknowledgement";
                myList.Stop();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                {
                    str = str + Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
                }
                SR.Write(str, 0, k);
            }

        }

    }
    catch (Exception f)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Error..... " + f; textBox2.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks more or less good in terms of logic and conditions. My only recomendation is use debugger, and do step-by-step crawling over server code. My first guess would be to check at last iteration (thats is not written to file) if this code `SR.Write(str, 0, k);` is executed with proper data.

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak. Followed your advise. When I debug the last value of "str" is the last data in the file which was send. However the .txt file still ends at the point I previous described. It doesn't matter if I enlarge byte array "b". I also tried not to empty "str" but just add all the received bytes to it and write it to the file after it hit the "break". Unfortunately the same result. Bit stuck here...

Comment: Found it!! Streamwriter.Autoflush=true did the trick